# How to prepare the third list using two lists using java 8

Tags: java, collections

I have a two different list and using those i have prepare third list using streams.

Student.java

```
public class Student {

    int id;
    String name;

    public Student(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

StudentLoc.java

```
public class StudentLoc {

    int id;
    String loc;

    public StudentLoc(int id, String loc) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

}
```

and I have third class like below.

StudentDetLoc.java

```
public class StudentDetLoc {

    int id;
    String name;
        String Loc;

}
```

1. I have to compare the Student list and StudentLoc list by using id property.
2. if id present in both list then i have to prepare StudentDetLoc list using both lists.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be:

1. Make set of student ids from first list using `streams()` and `map()`
2. Filter `filter()` second list using set obtained from step 1
3. Use `forEach()` as terminating operation of step 2 and append to final 3rd list (keeping only `id`, `name` and `Loc`).

Comment: CAN YOU PLEASE SHARE THE SAMPLE CODE